# How can i change the language in "Search results" message in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i'm trying to manage an E-shop with Prestashop. When i type in E-shop "Search box" a category or product, if any of these  doesn't exist, show the message "There are no products in this category". 
My question is, if anyone knows, how can i change the language in this message.

The prestashop version is 1.7.5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Two solutions :***

**1/ In your translations :**

You can edit these via the International > Translations tab in your PrestaShop admin panel:

[image]

You can then select Themes translations, your theme, your language and hit Modify:
[image]

Then, you can either search for "There are no products in this category[image]

**Or other solution edit TPL here :**

```
themes/yourthemes/templates/errors/not-found.tpl
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you! you helped me fix it! I appreciate it!